# File_get_content and Curl return nothing

Tags: php, curl, file-get-contents, flickr

I'm actually working with Flickr api. I create my Url request, and I send it on file_get_contents. All was worked fine, but today, all is broken!

When I use directly the request on my browser, all is working, but when I use file get content or Curl, it return an empty variable.

Here an exemple of my code :

```
$flickr_result = file_get_contents($request);
```

Or on Curl :

```
$cl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($cl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($cl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$ret = curl_exec($cl);
```

allow_fopen_url is "On", on my php.ini. The return value is not false.

I don't really understand, all was worked fine.

### Edit

This is what curl_getinfo print :

```
[content_type] => text/html; charset=UTF-8 
[http_code] => 302 
[header_size] => 838 
[request_size] => 218 
[filetime] => -1 
[ssl_verify_result] => 0 
[redirect_count] => 0 
[total_time] => 0.312 
[namelookup_time] => 0 
[connect_time] => 0.015 
[pretransfer_time] => 0.015 
[size_upload] => 0 
[size_download] => 0 
[speed_download] => 0 
[speed_upload] => 0 
[download_content_length] => 0 
[upload_content_length] => 0 
[starttransfer_time] => 0.312 
[redirect_time] => 0 
[certinfo] => Array ( ) 
[primary_ip] => 69.147.76.173 
[primary_port] => 80 
[local_ip] => 127.0.0.1 
[local_port] => 51014 
[redirect_url] => https://flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&api_key=XXXXXX&license=1,2,3,4,5,6&sort=interestingness-desc&text=toto&per_page=50&format=php_serial 
[request_header] => GET /services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&api_key=XXXXXX&license=1,2,3,4,5,6&sort=interestingness-desc&text=toto&per_page=50&format=php_serial HTTP/1.1 Host: flickr.com Accept: */*
```

Comment: any errors or warnings?

Comment: No error and warning. 
Curl_getinfo and curl_ernno print nothing..

Comment: Have you tried calling the url in a browser?

Comment: Set `CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT` option and show us what `print_r(curl_getinfo($hc, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT));` outputs

Comment: curl_getinfo with the header out return this :
GET /services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&api_key="I Hide my key"&license=1,2,3,4,5,6&sort=interestingness-desc&text=toto&per_page=50&format=php_serial HTTP/1.1 Host: flickr.com Accept: */*

Comment: @Jean Yim Not here. Add it into the question. And I requested all info, not just the header

Comment: When i call the url on my brower, it works...

Comment: Any idea ? :(
I'm fully lost..

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** Now seeing your curl output you get a 302 redirect from the API.

You cannot use file_get_content to get around that, but you can advise curl to follow the redirect on it's own with:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
```

---

How many requests have your made? Maybe you're reaching the quota - or Flickr disabled your API key.

---

Taken from https://www.flickr.com/services/developer/api/:

**Limits:** Since the Flickr API is quite easy to use, it's also quite easy to abuse, which threatens all services relying on the Flickr API. To help prevent this, we limit the access to the API per key. If your application stays under 3600 queries per hour across the whole key (which means the aggregate of all the users of your integration), you'll be fine. If we detect abuse on your key, we will need to expire the key, or turn it off, in order to preserve the Flickr API functionality for others (including us!). We also track usage on other factors as well to ensure no API user abuses the system.

Comment: I just called the api 10 or 15 times this day.. :/

Comment: Yeah, you were not calling the API too much, you're just getting a redirect, I updated my answer to reflect your situation.

Comment: Well, it works now! In local Curl with CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION doesn't want to work, but on the serveur, it works! Really thanks you!
(But i don't know why file get content stop to work..)
Thanks!

Comment: `file_get_content()` can't handle redirects, but since everything besides the protocol seems to be the same, I guess you made your requests to `http` instead of `https` and it seems that the flickr API changed those requests to be `https` - so you also might just change your first request url to start with `https://flickr.com/` and you no longer should get a redirect